# Open Links with Java On Other Computers

Tags: java, internet-explorer

So I'm currently programming a game right now where I want to create in-game voting. I managed to get sites to pop up, however, they don't pop up on the player's computer, but rather the server. I was wondering how to make it pop up on another person's computer...

```
    public static void openLink(String urlString) {
    try {
        Desktop.getDesktop().browse(new URL(urlString).toURI());
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

This currently of course opens the link on the server. I have methods to retrieve the player's client, but what exactly do I have to do to be able to do this?

I'm deving a game called Maplestory right now for educational purposes. I'm not too versed with dealing with anything concerning network, but I assume posting some code pertaining to the client might help.

```
public MapleClient(MapleAESOFB send, MapleAESOFB receive, IoSession session) {
    this.send = send;
    this.receive = receive;
    this.session = session;
}
```

That's the constructor class for the client. I know there's not enough information, but if it's requested I can continue to add more until it's solved. I tried looking online for help, but I have no clue.

Answer (score 0):

If you could post what game, the engine used, the server technology used, etc, we might be able to help more.

In general, this process is going to be a bit more involved than just a few lines of code on the server. As you've noticed, any action you take on the server is only going to happen on the server unless you architect it out.

Step one is to host your voting site somewhere/somehow (looks like you're already doing this.

Step two is to link this voting site to the clients somehow, so they know when/where to go.

After notifying the clients that they need to open the link, you need to actually open the link on each client.

I'd assume you already have the logic for sending the result back to the server in place based on your answer.

If you can post more details about the architecture of your project, it might be possible to give more specific help, but this isn't something that there is a built-in solution for, as far as I'm aware.

Comment: I'll continue adding edits until there seems to be an adequate amount of information. I'm not too versed with networking.

Comment: And yes I do. I have a method of retrieving it (API from the voting site).